# Lighten color using HSV?

Tags: java, android, hsv

In my code I have this:

```
public static int darkenColor(int color, float value) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    hsv[2] *= value; // value component

    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}
```

I want to create its counterpart, `lightenColor`. What is the correct formula?

Comment: what could be the counterpart of `*=` ...

Comment: value channel range is between 0 and 1. 0 is black 1 is white

Comment: In either the original or your new function, you should clamp the results to an acceptable ranges (like 0-255).

Answer (score 0):

```
hsv[2] = Math.pow(hsv[2], value)
```

always will be in [0..1] if value >= 0. You may use that formula for both methods.

Comment: And what will the other method look like? Same but with negative `value`?

Comment: if you want to incraise hsv[2] value must be in [0..1], if you need to decraise value must be in (1..infinity) - this is for one method. If you need two methods with the same range of value than you may use hsv[2]=Math.pow(hsv[2], value) for darkenColor, and hsv[2]=Math.pow(hsv[2], 1 / value) for lightenColor, where value >= 1.

Comment: The inverse `1 / value` makes sense. I cannot understand this `pow` usage though. Can you point to a source that explains why it should be used instead of multiplication? E.g. 100*0.3 != pow(100, 0.3)

Comment: I just adviced you to use `pow`, because it guarantees that your `hsv[2]` value will be always in [0..1] range.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@ColorInt
public static int lightenColor(@ColorInt int color) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    hsv[2] *= 1.4f;
    return Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
}
```

You can change color effect by changing the {hsv[2] *= 1.4f}